# How to programmatically add new nodequeue?

Tags: drupal

I'm writing an install file for a custom module, that needs to create some new nodequeues.  But a drupal and google search are so far turning up empty.  Anyone know how to do this?

Drupal 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closet thing you come to a API function to save nodes is [nodequeue_save](http://api.lullabot.com/nodequeue_save), but all you really need to do, is to insert some data to the `{nodequeue_queue}` table. You can do it yourself with SQL or use the function, but the result will be the same.

You should remember to add the nodequeue module as a dependency in your module's info file and check if it's installed before running your stuff in `hook_install`.

Comment: In addition, you should make sure there are no nodequeue-addons that need to be noticed of changes. Nodequeue_save, nor manually inserting will notice them: such modules typically add their own listereners (so called submit callbacks) to forms. Results may become unexpected when queues are inserted into the database directly.

Comment: Thanks googletorp and berkes.  I was coming to similar conclusions, and you've verified for me.  I appreciate that...

Comment: You really should avoid writing directly to the database in this case. Use the API.

Answer (score -1):

Some API documentation might help you on the road? http://api.lullabot.com/file/contrib/nodequeue/nodequeue.module

Comment: It ís the official documentation, not just a link to the sourcecode.

Comment: It's not the official documentation. Lullabot have created that from the source code with the same module that powers api.drupal.org. Still providing a list of functions in a module's module file is not helpful.

Comment: seems that address has been changed, I found this  http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21nodequeue%21nodequeue.module/7